# Facebook: Best way to allow one Facebook user to send a secure link to another Facebook user?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hey, I'm a product management guy looking to understand how we can deliver audio clips into Facebook. Specifically, I'd like to allow a user (a "sender") who is logged into my iPhone app through Facebook connect to send a link for an audio file to another Facebook user (a "recipient" who has never logged into my app).  I understand that it's not currently possible for this link to be sent as an outside email to the recipient, or even as an internal Facebook message.  Is that still true?

If so, I'm wondering if it's possible (and advisable?) to post it as a chat message, or as an invite that is posted to the recipient's wall. For the chat message, if it's possible then what are the downsides of that method?  For the invite, I realize the wall post will only be visible to the recipient, but I'm concerned that the recipient may not realize that and will think that the audio file is available to anyone who views his profile.

As such, for the invite method, I'd like to require the recipient (after they click a link in the wall post invite) to login to our web site where the audio is hosted via Facebook connect before listening to the audio. Is it possible to accomplish that?  In other words, will I be able to know when the person logs in through Facebook connect that he is the recipient? In addition to a token in the audio link URL, how do I track that? Will I need to track a user ID or something?

Thanks in advance for your thoughts!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go with the wallpost method.

I'd implement it by letting the initial user share a link on a friend's wall saying "User has shared a song with you! Click here to open it!" or something like that. When any user clicks that link, prompt for install and once they're authenticated, show them any files that are theirs (and yes, you'll need to check their user ID vs. the user IDs that were stored as links in your database).

If it's not the friend who clicks the link, they won't see anything (or they'll see something different). You could even use a customized link and show an error if an unauthorized user clicks to that page.

For what it's worth, this is how Amazon handles giving Amazon gift cards via Facebook.

If this is unclear or too vague, let me know and I'll clarify.

Comment: +1, I can't think of a better way. And doing so, you increase the traffic to your site (since friends of friend will click AND "connect" to your site) and if the landing user isn't the user you are looking for show them an offer or something!